# Can I install MSDN 2005 into VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msdn

I have MSDN for Visual Studio 2005. Just a week ago, I upgraded to Visual Studio 2010. But I don't have any offline help for visual studio. I cannot connect to the Internet from the computer having VS2010. I go to an internet cafe for internet access. I found that the entire MSDN for VS2010 weighs **6.48 GB**.

Can I install and integrate the MSDN2005 into VS2010?

Comment: But I'm running in Windows. But if you can suggest me some Linux IDE, it would be great.

Comment: Also, the applications cannot be run on windows platform later.

Comment: Suggestions for resource are also off-topic here. I like using `emacs` (I have no idea what is an IDE to you) on Linux. I never used Windows for development work (my first program was on punched cards in PL/1, about 1974; I'm using Unix since 1987 and Linux since 1993.).

Comment: Basile : Had you worked on first or second generation computers? I want to discuss you something. Will you share your mail id to me?

Comment: My email is publicly available, and no, I didn't work on second generation computers.